# php unit testing - Property does not exist

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, testing

I am creating some test cases for my application and i am stuck at a point. I am trying to set a property to the class. But its a parent Class property. This is my actual method

```
public function uploadFiles($files, $endpoint = 'outbox', $config = [])
    {
        $user = $this->_BxApi->users->getUser($config);
        $result = [];
        foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
            $policy = 'policy' . $key;
            $result[] = $this->_fileUploader->uploadFile($file, $policy, $config);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

This is a method in Class `Uploads` which extent Class `API` and the API class is

```
class Api
{

    public function __construct(BxClient $bxclient)
    {
        $this->_BxApi = $bxclient;
    }
}
```

And my test case is

```
public function testUploadFiles_Upload2Files()
{
    $bxMock = $this->_getMock(\BxClient\Core\Api\Uploads::class, [
        '_request' => true
    ]);

    $this->_setProperty($bxMock, 'users', $this->_getMock(Users::class, [
        'getUser' => (object) ['userId' => 'test']
    ]));
    $this->_setProperty($bxMock, '_fileUploader', $this->_getMock(FileUploader::class, [
        'uploadFile' => true,
    ]));

    $result = $bxMock->uploadFiles(['1.txt', '2.txt']);

    $this->assertEquals(2, count($result));
    $this->assertTrue($result[0]);
    $this->assertTrue($result[1]);
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong in

```
$this->_setProperty($bxMock, 'users', $this->_getMock(Users::class, [
        'getUser' => (object) ['userId' => 'test']
    ]));
```

**Update**
This is the error

> ReflectionException: Property users does not exist

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have class `Uploads` that extend class `API`. Class `API` have inner object in property `_BxApi`. This inner object have field `users`. But in code you try set property to  instance of `Uploads` instead of inner object from `_BxApi` field.

You should set field `users` to your inner object in `_BxApi` field.

**Updated:**

Your code should look like this pseudo-code:

```
$bxMock = $this->_getMock(BxClient::class, [arguments goes here]);
$this->_setProperty($bxMock, 'users', $this->_getMock(Users::class, [
    'getUser' => (object) ['userId' => 'test']
]));
$uploads = $this->_getMock(\BxClient\Core\Api\Uploads::class, [
    '_BxApi' => $bxMock,
]);
```

Main idea next - firstly, you create inner object (`$bxMock`) that will be placed to `Uploads` instance, then you create instance of `Uploads` itself and place in it your previously created inner object (`$bxMock`).

Comment: @ManojKumar, did it help?